# Doing DFT before calling Opencv filter2D function

Tags: opencv, image-processing, filtering

I am generating filter bank response for an image using Opencv filter2D. Given my filter sizes filter2D function is doing DFT based convolution. My filter bank size is 10, for 9/10 times DFT computation of the image is redundant. Is there any way to get DFT computation of the image out of the filter2D function ? This will save lot of time.
Regards